# Ansible - include one playbook into another in loop

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I am new to ansible and trying to figure out how can I call one playbook from another playbook in loop. I also want to consume the output back in master playbook. Not sure if it could be possible in Ansible.

Below is a stub from other programming languages -

```
masterplaybook.yml - from where I want to invoke auditplaybook

   for devicePair in devicePairList
        output = auditdevice.yml -e "d1=devicePair.A d2=devicePair.B"
    save/process output
```

auditdevice.yml playbook is using d1 and d2 as hosts on which it is performing auditing, running commands etc. It is performing audit on dynamic inventory passed as part of argument.

Is it possible to achieve above using Ansible? If yes, can someone point to any example?

Comment: As pointed out by Vladimir, this is not possible with `include_playbook`. But `include_tasks` can be used in a task with a loop. See the doc about [including and importing](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_reuse_includes.html)

Comment: Is it possible to include play's into a loop? As I need to run play on dynamic inventory.

Comment: No. You can specify the play `hosts` as a variable though.

Answer (score 1):

> Q: *"How can I call one playbook from another playbook in the loop?"*

A: It is not possible. Quoting from [import_playbook](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/import_playbook_module.html#import-playbook-import-a-playbook)

> "You cannot use this action inside a play."

See the [example](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/import_playbook_module.html#examples).

---

FWIW. [ansible-runner](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-runner) is able to controll playbooks withing projects similar to AWX. See [example](https://ansible-runner.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python_interface.html#usage-examples).